# Best method to handle unknown class in supervised classification

Tags: classification, supervised-learning

I have a training dataset, where the records are labelled into 3 classes: A, B and C.
My testing dataset consists of records that belong to classes A, B, C and records that do not belong to any of the above. Let's call this 'U' (i.e., Unknown)

**My question**: What is the best method that I can use to identify records that belong classes A,B,C as belonging to classes A,B,C respectively and anything that does not belong to any of these as Unknown?

I would appreciate if the answer contains some references as well.

PS:

1. I went through [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148106/how-to-handle-unknown-class-during-classification), but I am not sure it is applicable to my scenario
2. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174484/classification-with-unknown-class) is similar, but the answer requires having some data from the Unknown class in my training data, which is not practical for my scenario
3. I think this is the correct site for this question based on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms). If not please let me know!

Comment: At the moment, I use an isolation forest to check if the data record is unknown, and if it is not, I use a random forest to classify it into either A,B or C. This works well, but I am looking for a one step solution.